# React Material UI Tabs Close

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am implementing material ui tabs with close functionality. On the close tab not able to set the  active tab value in the current tab. its giving warning error.

code in the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-bas-fi8oe)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When clicking the close icon, you're not only executing `handleClose` but also the `handleChange` function. This happens because of the principle called event bubbling.

> When an event happens on an element, it first runs the handlers on it, then on its parent, then all the way up on other ancestors.

Source: [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing)

--

To fix your issue, you have to stop the event propagation on close icon's click event. Modify your `handleClose` to

```js
const handleClose = useCallback(
    (event, tabToDelete) => {
      // stop event from propagating to the target element's parent
      event.stopPropagation(); 

      const tabToDeleteIndex = activetabs.findIndex(
        tab => tab.id === tabToDelete.id
      );
      const updatedTabs = activetabs.filter((tab, index) => {
        return index !== tabToDeleteIndex;
      });
      const previousTab =
        activetabs[tabToDeleteIndex - 1] ||
        activetabs[tabToDeleteIndex + 1] ||
        {};
      setActiveTabs(updatedTabs);
      setActiveTab(previousTab.id);
    },
    [activetabs]
  );
```

...now you call that using

```js
<a
   className="closeTab"
   title={"Close tab"}
   onClick={(event) => handleClose(event, tab)}
>
   <CloseIcon />
</a>
```

PS: If you want to use `IconButton` component instead of `a` tag, use

```js
<IconButton component="div" onClick={(event) => handleClose(event, tab)}>
   <CloseIcon />
</IconButton>
```

that will avoid you from getting the error from material-ui, which you might have already encountered.

```
Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <button> cannot appear as a descendant of <button>.
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-closeable-tab-gw2hw?file=/src/components/tabsdemo/index.jsx)

Comment: Thanks for looking into this.